# Is there an equivalence to “steal a glance/look at” for the word “love”?

Tags: phrase-request

Obviously, I know “steal a love” doesn’t work, and “love secretly” doesn’t have the same dramatic feeling.

*I’d like to make my point clear:* “steal a glance/look at” is a dramatic way of saying “look secretly at”. So what is the dramatic way of saying “love secretly”?

Here’s sentence by sentence comparison:

> He looks at her.
>
> He loves her.

---

> He looks at her secretly.
>
> He loves her secretly.

---

> He steals a glance at her.
>
> What’s the “equivalence” here?

Comment: I think it would help make it more clear if you came up with an example of how you would like to use the phrase.

Comment: @ColleenV I thought it’d suffice without example. But I’ll do as you suggested.

Comment: An example sentence is worth a hundred words sometimes :)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to say:

> He **has a crush on** her.

since **"having a crush on someone"** [means](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+a+crush+on+(someone)):

> To have a romantic infatuation with someone, especially
>   **unbeknownst** to that person.

---

Or you can say:

> He loves her **from afar**.

Here is the [definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/from%20afar) for **"from afar"**:

> from a great distance

---

You may also want to use **"unspoken love"**. The following paragraph is from *The Guardian*:

> In the first scene, celebrating Guy's flat-warming, we not only learn
>   that he has long had **an unspoken love for** his old university chum,
>   John: we also discover that the rootless John has been having a secret
>   affair with Reg, the lover of another old mate from uni days, the
>   flamboyant Daniel.